# Does Containment Priest exile one's own creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Containment Priest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Containment%20Priest) says "If a nontoken creature would enter...exile it instead," but it doesn't specify "opponent," so does casting this creature mean that Containment Priest's controller would also have to exile all noncasted nontoken creatures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does casting this creature mean that Containment Priest's controller would also have to exile all noncasted nontoken creatures?

Yes, when it comes to creatures entering the battlefield *after* Containment Priest. It does not mean you have to exile all existing non-token creatures.

Creatures entering *simultaneously* (including the Priest itself if it isn't cast) won't be affected, as is reflected by the rulings under the card in Gatherer:

> - If Containment Priest enters the battlefield without being cast, its ability won’t exile itself.
> - If Containment Priest enters the battlefield at the same time as other creatures, its ability won’t affect those creatures.

Comment: To add: _Containment Priest_ can be cast after a creature-summoning effect goes onto the stack to exile such a non-token creature.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this ability affects your own creatures as well as your opponent's. Note that it does not affect any creatures that are already in play when the Priest enters, or the Priest itself if for some reason it is entering the battlefield without being cast.